# What is the adverb for 'seasoned'?

Tags: adverbs

I am looking for a word that means the blend of maturely, beautifully, and correctly and has to be used the way some art is executed, for example:

*Just for the sheer beauty of it, without understanding it, do you enjoy any language? if spoken **in a seasoned way**?*

*I fell in love with her house! the calligraphy on her wall was done so **seasonedly**?*

I know that word doesn't exist, that's why I am asking :)

Comment: Thank you everyone for the clarification! I have accepted the one that provided both the analysis of the problem and its solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think I'd use *seasoned* like that. It means flavoured, prepared or weathered; not mature, beautiful and correct. Perhaps the word you're looking for is **expertly** or **artfully**, which would fit both examples.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, I don't think that "**seasoned**" means what you think it means. "**Seasoned**" does *not* mean "mature, beautiful, and correct". It simply means "[experienced](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/seasoned)", "[matured or  ripened](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/season#Verb)"; in referenced to food, "spiced"; or in reference to wood and similar materials, "dried and aged".

So it carries the connotation of maturity, but not of beauty or correctness. The word does have a slightly positive or approving connotation, but it wouldn't be advisable to use it in the way you describe.

There is no adverb form of "**seasoned**"; we would simply say "**in a seasoned way**".

Regarding this part of the question: "*a word that means the blend of maturely, beautifully, and correctly and has to be used the way some art is executed*"; all I can think of is "**cultivated**" or "**cultured**."  The adverbial forms of the former is "**cultivatedly**" though this is rare. There is no single-word adverb for the latter.

You might also try "**elegantly**" or "**sophisticatedly**".

Comment: Much thanks! I just took seasoned speaker = good orator => beautiful speech. But thanks. So, can you tell me the adverb for cultivated or cultured?

Comment: If in doubt, just compliment a woman by calling her seasoned and see what happens

Comment: You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means.

Answer (score 3):

I would use *tasteful* or *tastefully*.

Answer (score 0):

*The calligraphy on her wall was so seasoned. It positively reeked of a blend of coriander, turmeric, cumin, cardamom and star anise.*

Drop the useless "do" and the need for an adverb vaporizes. We know that calligraphy was "done"; it doesn't spontaneously appear.

But I would suggest "crafted by a seasoned hand".  Putting meaning into language is a little bit like painting in watercolor. For example, the attachment of this "seasoned" adjective can shift between the object and the agent which produced the object. The meaning is approximately the same. It's the experience of the craftsman which makes the work seasoned anyway; it is the craftsman whose skill is seasoned.